# problems with react-material-ui-carousel - can not display three cards in one row

Tags: reactjs, carousel

I am trying to create a carousel with material ui and I am having the problem that I can not display three cards in one row at a time, It only shows one of the cards. Could you please help me to address this issue? Thanks in advance

This is the component that I am iterating through an array of objects and pass it to Carousel component

```
import React from "react";

import {
  Card,
  Container,
  Typography,
  CardContent,
  Button,
  Grid, Container
} from "@material-ui/core";
import Carousel from "react-material-ui-carousel";
import DayCardItem from "./DayCardItem";


const DayCard = (props) => {
  const { dailyData } = props;

  const classes = useStyles();
  return (

    <Container>
      <Grid>
        <Carousel
          autoPlay={false}
          animation={"fade"}
          navButtonsAlwaysVisible={true}
        >
          {dailyData &&
            dailyData.map((day, index) => (
              <DayCardItem key={index} day={day} />
            ))}
        </Carousel>
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default DayCard;
```

After that in DayCardItem I am getting the props and showing them in a Card component from material ui

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Card,
  Container,
  Typography,
  CardContent,
  Button,
  Grid,
} from "@material-ui/core";


const DayCardItem = (props) => {
  const { day } = props;

  return (
    <Grid item  item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography>{day.dt}</Typography>
        <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
         {day.main.temp}
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default DayCardItem;
```

This is the UI that I am getting after rendering these two components
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try set height and width

```
carousel :{
    height : "200px",
    width : "100%",
    "& img" : {
        height : "200px",
        width: "-webkit-fill-available"
    }
},
<Carousel autoPlay={false}  className={classes.carousel}>
        <div>
            <img alt="" src={projectImage} />
            <p className="legend">Legend 1</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img alt="" src={projectImage} />
            <p className="legend">Legend 2</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img alt="" src={projectImage} />
            <p className="legend">Legend 3</p>
        </div>
       
    </Carousel>
```